# Using 3 conditions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to extract data using three conditions.

I have very sensitive information, so I am only able to provide some basic data below.

What I am trying to output from using 3 lists is that if a particular team is selected, while also selecting the relevant month and points, then output from a range of values

I have been using SUMPRODUCT() for 2 conditions and it works fine, as soon as the third condition is selected, it does not recognise any data

Please see some primitive data which I have created. For example, how would i extract the points total for Everton in the month of December in country Ireland? Answer should be "35"

```
football team   month     country     points 
liverpool       january   scotland    59 
everton         march     france      25 
man u           april     wales       65 
spurs           may       ireland     89 
liverpool       june      ireland     45 
spurs           july      scotland    65 
man u           august    wales       14 
everton         september england     25 
man u           october   wales       49 
liverpool       november  scotland    25 
everton         december  ireland     35
```

Any advice?

Thanks

---

Thanks you both for your help.

Unfortunately my query is a little more complicated than that. I am developing a summary tab of hundreds of thousands lines of data, so I am looking to set up 3 lists where the user can select a different option (country, team and month) in each one to bring up a different set of results.

I am very comfortable with developing pivot tables, but do you know if there is a way of developing a pivot table with 3 different conditions.

Robert, on your pivot table you have team and country in the same column, is there a way of breaking this into two and then being able to use a formula to search for all three conditions?

Brian, as some of the people using the spreadsheet which I am trying to adapt are not very proficient in excel, I don't think that they would have the necessary experience to start playing around with formulas as simple as it seems to us :-) Would you have a way to make this more generic?

---

Thanks for both of your ideas. I think I am getting close to the answer, but Excel is finding it hard to compute what I am trying to do.

If I try to give a little more detail without disclosing any confidential information. What I am doing is trying to create a dashboard, so I have various drop down boxes which are sourcing their data from various other pivot tables in different tabs.

In the primitive sample I provided, if you can imagine that I would have the football teams on the left. Along the columns I have month and country and the pivot values are the points. I know that there is not a lot of information above, so I have provided a little more

If in the columns each month has several countries, this means that there will be repeats of relevant countries within each month. I think Excel is getting confused because this data is not unique and when it searches it is picking up the first instance of this country and when it sees the next, it gets confused and outputs nothing.

Is there a way of somehow partitioning the data and maybe creating a loop, so that it will continue to search the other parts of the table until it finds the value that satisfies all three conditions. I hate using loops as I am not fully comfortable with them, hence why I have not mentioned it before, but I feel this is the only way that I am going to be able to resolve this.

I dont think the data below will format the way i want it but hopefully when pasted into Excel, you can just do Text to Columns

```
football team   month   country points
liverpool   january scotland    59
everton march   france  25
man u   april   wales   65
spurs   may ireland 89
liverpool   june    ireland 45
spurs   july    scotland    65
man u   august  wales   14
everton september   england 25
man u   october wales   49
liverpool   november    scotland    25
everton december    ireland 35
man u   february    scotland    22
liverpool   october france  51
everton december    wales   54
spurs   august  ireland 69
spurs   may ireland 84
liverpool   march   scotland    51
everton may wales   64
man u   december    england 35
liverpool   november    wales   35
everton june    scotland    25
spurs   july    ireland 74
everton april   scotland    83
man u   january france  65
liverpool   june    wales   48
everton november    ireland 98
spurs   december    ireland 51
liverpool   december    scotland    44
everton february    wales   2
spurs   november    england 66
```

Thanks again for all your help

Comment: It wont let me post the data in a recognised column and row format

Answer (score 4):

I think `SUMIFS()` should suit your purpose.

`SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], [criteria_range3, criteria3])`.

So for your example, `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"everton",B:B,"december",C:C,"ireland")`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, my recommendation would be to create a pivot table. Follow the process outline below for a ugly version.

1. Enter the data you've provided above into a blank spreadsheet.
2. Highlight all of the data and click "Format as Table" (Style is irrelevant), accept defaults and click 'ok'.
3. Now that you have a proper table, under "Table Tools > Design" you'll see an option to "Summarize with PivotTable", choose that. Accept defaults and click 'ok'.
4. On the right side of the screen is "PivotTable Field List". Check all four options in this list and you see your PivotTable start building on the left side. At this point, the answer to your question above is already clear: Everton scored 35pts in the Month of December in Ireland.

Additional formatting is available to your liking, as is exchanging rows for columns to reorganize.

Google is loaded with more information on how to create and manipulate Excel PivotTables to meet your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a new answer based on Brian's answer. I'm not trying to steal the answer, but Niall mentioned that Brian's formula requires "users to modify formulas". The simple solution to that (as I'm sure Brian was aware of) is to use this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,G1,B:B,G2,C:C:G3)
```

In this case, put "everton" into cell G1, "december" into cell G2 and "ireland" into cell G3.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIFS` wil work here but this is a classic case for `DSUM`.

`=DSUM(A3:D14,"points",A1:D2)`

-in row three user can enter the criteria( like "france", ">10" etc..)
-you can take multiple agruments if needed 
- the second argument ofcourcse can also be changed to whichever column( provided it has numbers in it)

There is a lot that you can do with this [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DSUM-function-f1852179-31db-457a-919d-3eef112f8c6f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is documentation on it

```
 1 football team   month     country     points 
 2                           scotland            
 3 football team   month     country     points 
 4 liverpool       january   scotland    59 
 5 everton         march     france      25 
 6 man u           april     wales       65 
 7 spurs           may       ireland     89 
 8 liverpool       june      ireland     45 
 9 spurs           july      scotland    65 
10 man u           august    wales       14 
11 everton         september england     25 
12 man u           october   wales       49 
13 liverpool       november  scotland    25 
14 everton         december  ireland     35
```